# How to create incremental numbers in InDesign or Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I have an A3 layout with several tickets to be printed, each with an consecutive number. Is there a way to do it automatically instead of writing it by hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally use "Data Merge" in InDesign and use Excel (or something like it) to generate the list of numbers for me. You would copy the numbers into a text file so that InDesign can read them as the merge data source. Note that you would have one ticket on the page and then let InDesign set the other tickets on the page (you can tell the Data Merge control panel about spacing).

You can also get creative with "Bullets and Numbering" -- but I haven't tried that.

The nice part of using Data Merge is that you can also put in sections, prices, etc. and have those change according to the seat -- then save the text file and use it next season.

Comment: thanks, I found this great tutorial about Data Marged: http://www.theindesigner.com/podcasts/tid43_theindesigner_43.mp4

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. There are 2 methods mentioned on the [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2355759#2355759). Check replies 1 and 4.

Comment: It would be nice if the this answer contained the relevant information. A snippet or even an excerpt would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Are leading zeros important? If not this is easy in indesign:

On a master page, create a text box. rightclick/insert special character/markers/current page number (also under the type menu). Have your ticket image on the master page too, then just create x number pages for x number of tickets.

If you want leading zeros you could get fancy with multiple master pages or maybe sections, or someone might have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac computers

In text edit, create new document
In Menu Format select Make Rich text

create a table containing cells 1 column and required number of Rows e.g. 50

select the table cells...

Go in Styles List...

select any text as per choice in prefix (e.g. Bill No/ receipt no./) or leave blank,

select 123 numbers and any text of choice in suffix
and Hit ok..

Answer (score 0):

http://textmechanic.co/Generate-List-of-Numbers.html

Just arrange your text boxes in place and paste the generated numbering on illustrator